# What user runs the user-data script when starting up a new ubuntu EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rsync

I'm trying to launch an EC2 instance with a script in the user-data. The script contains an rsync call to a remote server but this fails. I believe this is because I need to setup the user that runs the user-data to be able to connect to the remote server.

What user runs the user-data script?

The `stderr` that I have logged is:

```
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the script is run as `root`. So if you have to communicate via SSH, make sure that the root account is able to make the connections.